# python - communicating with other applications at high rate

Tags: python, ipc, dllimport

I have a Python function `get_messages()` that is able to retrieve messages from another application via a dll. These messages arrive at a rate of about 30hz, and I need to fill a buffer with these messages, while the main Python application is running and doing things with theses messages. I believe the filling of the buffer should occur in a separate thread. My question is: what is the best Pythonic way to retrieve these messages ? (running a loop in a separate thread is probably not the best solution). Is there a module that is dedicated to this sort of tasks?

Comment: You may want to consider the `asyncio` module, a new addition in python 3.4. It comes with an event loop that achieves non-blocking I/O similar to JavaScript. https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html

Comment: thx. Do you know a comprehensive introduction to asyncio? the manual is somewhat hard.

Answer (score 0):

Answer according to Doug Ross: consider the Asyncio module.